# How to convert json object to string array

Tags: java, android, json

I have got a null String variable and String array is stock string variable like this:

```
String value1;
String value2;

String[] arr = {value1,value2};
```

And in **JSON** object I try coding like this:

```
for(int i=0;i < jLocation.length();i++){
    value1 = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    value2 = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("location");
}
```

But not return value into variable. How to resolve problem?

Comment: Please clarify _But not return value into variable_.

Comment: Please take some time to read the [help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named "What topics can I ask about here?" and "What types of questions should I avoid asking?". And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Post your whole code. How did  you define and assign value to jLocation?

Comment: In my screen show empty listview.

Comment: Your for loop start from variable i (i-0) where it is declared, please put your complete code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look like you want to store name and location in an array, if yes then

```
for(int i=0; i < jLocation.length(); i++){
    arr[0] = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    arr[1] = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("location");
}
```

**Note** - This code assume that you only have one name and location. However I sugegst you to do something like below:

Create a `Location` class, e.g. below

```
public class Location {
    private String name;
    private String location;

    public Location(String name, String location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
}
```

Then use it like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

        for(int i=0; i < jLocation.length(); i++){
            String name = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            String location = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("location");

            locations.add(new Location(name, location));
        } 
    }
```

Comment: I should use ArrayList<Location> matching ArrayAdapter<Location> Right?

Comment: What you are using ArrayAdapter? What is the final output you expect?

Comment: I want to get some json object to string array and show them in list view. Sorry I'm beginner for android :C

Comment: Not sure how to do it in `Android`. But since you already have a list of `Location` object you just need to `iterate` on the list and get the `name` and `location`.

Comment: Thank you @TheCodingFrog for your advising. Have a nice day guy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//First initiate string
String value1;
String value2;

//Read json
for(int i-0;i < jLocation.length();i++){
    value1 = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    value2 = jLocation.getJSONObject(i).getString("location");
} 

//Create Stting array
String[ ] arr = {value1,value2};
```

It will use to add only one value to array.

I prefer `ArrayList`. Then you can add all the data to ArrayList